# Where and how to import MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Following this example [Form field with label](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview), I tried to change the behavior of `mat-form-field` placeholder. There are three options:
`auto`, `always` and `never`.

The feature is really a good one and can be used depending on which kind of placeholder developer would like to implement.

And actually it can be used globally passing it directly to `@NgModule` of the app root:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: {float: 'always'}}
  ]
})
```

and building the view as following:

```
<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="never"> // never, auto or always
   <input matInput placeholder="Simple placeholder" required>
</mat-form-field>
```

My issue is that I first don't find/know where I exactly can/should import: `MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS` as it seems that it doesn't exist in `@angular/material` and if I check on this [GitHub-Repo](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/form-field/form-field.ts), I see that it's imported from `@angular/material/core`, but it doesn't work form me, cause I get the following error:

`/node_modules/@angular/material/core"' has no exported member 'MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS'. Did you mean 'MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS'?`

Has it to do with the material and CLI version I'am using?

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.0
Node: 8.0.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.0.0-rc.2
@angular/cli: 1.5.0
@angular/material: 5.0.0-rc.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.33
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.21
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.37
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.7
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1
```

Comment: have you tried the new version of material:  "^5.2.3"?  `import {MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS} from "@angular/material";` it can be imported from the material package according to my project.

Comment: This would mean that I have to upgrade my `@angular/material` cause as you can see, I do have: `@angular/material: 5.0.0-rc.2`

Comment: I am sure the version 5.2.3 can import it. And according to the source code the 5.0.0-rc.2 didn't have the file of the name `label-options.ts` https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/d6fec3573cbc854d5bf67d920c5b0f8a6eef0c86/src/lib/core/label/label-options.ts where the MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS exported. so I think this version should use old option: MAT_PLACEHOLDER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, see this https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/26ee3e77fcd6183d0b2f5495d9a79f8d294d4037

Comment: this commit https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/d6fec3573cbc854d5bf67d920c5b0f8a6eef0c86#diff-ef8c238b58a4c74aae9916a4c75635b6

Comment: upgrade to 5.0.0-rc.3 and try, I think it should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum version of material to support `MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS` is **5.0.0-rc.3**.

Because it is exported in this file: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/5.0.0-rc.3/src/lib/core/label/label-options.ts, but the rc.2 don't have this file
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/5.0.0-rc.2/src/lib/core/label/label-options.ts page not found. So try to update to RC.3.

See the 5.0.0-rc.3 release note: https://github.com/angular/material2/releases/tag/5.0.0-rc.3

> form-field: add support for separate label and placeholder (#8223) (d6fec35), closes #6194

this feature add new export const: `MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS`

Comment: Now I did upgrade my `@angular/material` to `"@angular/material": "^5.2.4"`and tried: `import { MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material';` but it still throws the same error.

Comment: Look good. It seems to be working fine. I assume that's the Visual Studio Code throws this error and might missed some angular extension. Every thing looks good including compiling.

Comment: Great! glad to hear that.

Answer (score 9):

In Angular 9 this has [changed again](https://github.com/angular/components/commit/bfdf3239a10d0fe4c4f28d3bf845afc5335f4d88):

> As of Angular Material version 9, the `MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS`
> injection token is deprecated. The default floating label behavior
> should be set through the `MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` token.

Current way is therefore to add `{ provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { floatLabel: 'always' } }` to the providers array of your module.

For this to work in Angular 11

```
import { MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/form-field';
```